# Automatically change virtualenvs in Pycharm when switching to a new branch

Tags: mercurial, virtualenv, pycharm

To bypass dependency conflicts, my team is migrating to a new setup where each branch of our build will have different virtualenvs (with different dependencies in requirements.txt files for pip to install). The entire team is on Pycharm and mercurial.

**Question**: Is there an easy way to have Pycharm ***automatically*** switch to the respective virtualenv when switching between branches? I stress *automatically*, because we devs switch between different branches many times a day, and if we forget to change virtualenvs it can be problematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to implement this via a post-update hook:

Commit to each branch a description file or better a small script which - when called - updates your environment to however you need it. And have the hook check for the presence of that script and call it when found.

Backdraw: every developer has to install that hook in his own .hgrc. But that's a one-time setup compared to manual update every time :)

Comment: I got this up and running! My problem now is that my virtualenv isn't being activated when the post update hook is ran. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532382/mercurial-update-hook-not-activating-python-virtual-environment