# Mercurial update hook not activating Python virtual environment

Tags: python, bash, mercurial, virtualenv

I have a bash script that I'm trying to execute anytime an `hg update` occurs. The goal of this bash script is to switch to the correct virtualenv. For the sake of simplicity, this script is called `.test` - shown as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'testing hg update hook'
source ~/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

Whenever I call this script from my shell using `source .test` everythying works properly; I can see the results of echo and my shell changes to reflect the activated virtualenv

However,when I do an `hg update`, the virtualenv is not being activated. The script is firing as I can see the echo result; however, my shell is not updated to reflect the activated virtualenv. Below is the hook setup in my `.hg/hgrc` file is below. Any ideas why my virtualenv isn't being activated in this hook?

```
[hooks]
# Update to the correct virtualenv when switching branches (hg update branchname)
update = source .test
```

**UPDATE 1:** Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369145/activating-a-virtualenv-using-a-shell-script-doesnt-seem-to-work), I don't believe the `hg update` hook is firing in my current shell; which is why the virtualenv activates when I run the script manually but fails from the hook

Comment: Where do you expect the virtualenv to be activated? It's only going to be active for the duration of the subshell which doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hm, that seems more tricky. Not sure there's a satisfying solution to that. In my answer to your other question I didn't consider that the virtualenv is only transient to the shell it is generated in. Does your IDE have an API which allows to modify / interact with the shell it offers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script maybe has some half-answer and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you invoke a shell script, any changes to the environment variables do not get exported to the calling shell (hence why you need to call `source activate` from the surrounding shell).

The good news is that you don't strictly *need* to call `activate` in order to access a virtual environment. What `activate` will do is:

1. Add the virtualenv's `bin` directory to `$PATH`.
2. Set the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.
3. Modify your prompt.

None of this is necessary in order to use the virtualenv, and you can execute the `python` binary in the virtualenv without ever using the script; the prompt is likely not relevant for your use case, you can add the directory (or just the `python` executable) to your path by symlinking it, and you need the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable only for software that for some reason needs to be aware of the virtualenv it's running in. If necessary, you can figure it out from `sys.executable`. For example:

```
import sys, os

def find_venv():
  python = sys.executable
  for i in xrange(10):
    if not os.path.islink(python):
      break
    python = os.path.realpath(python)
  return os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(python))

if not os.environ.has_key("VIRTUAL_ENV"):
  os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"] = find_venv()
```